# Getting SharePoint to read Apache Solr index

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, enterprise-search

I've a SP 2013 site which I want to read search indexes from Apache Solr (Drupal application).

So far I cannot seems to find a way to do it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If by "read" you mean "search" then you have to crawl the content. SharePoint won't do anything with the index itself, you have to direct SharePoint to crawl the same content.